# Format Previous month with its year

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datetime

i don't know how to deal with this...

say currently, it's 2013/11/27, so it will be 2013/10 for previous month.

I searched there's something like (DateTime.Now.Month - 1), but how do I keep track of year please?

and say 2014 January, how do I turn it to 201312?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use [`DateTime.AddMonths`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like;

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
now = now.AddMonths(-1);
Console.WriteLine(now.ToString("yyyyMM"));
```

Output will be;

```
201310
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/mz0G98)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DateTime.AddMonths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

Answer (score 0):

Use `AddMonth` method of DateTime class to subtract a month:

```
var previousMoth = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
var year = previousMoth.Year;
var month = previousMoth.Month;
var day = previousMoth.Day;
```